# OAuthService.fetchTokenUsingPasswordFlow of angular-oauth2-oidc TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'access_token')

Tags: oauth-2.0, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-6.0, angular15

I am migrating an ASP.NET core 3.1 project into core 6.0 (backend) and Angular 9 to Angular 15 (frontend). After fixing many issues, I got the app to launch again. The problem I am facing now is the use of `angular-oauth2-oidc` library to do user login with password flow. It is getting the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'access_token')
```

My Angular login code is as below:

```
async login(userName: string, password: string): Promise<LoginResult> {
    if (userName === null || userName === undefined || password === null || password === undefined) {
      return { success: false, failureMessage: "Username and Password are required" } as LoginResult;
    }

    //https://github.com/manfredsteyer/angular-oauth2-oidc/blob/master/docs-src/password-flow.md
    try {
      console.log('passed in credentials: ' + userName + '-' + password);
      let token = await this.oauthService.fetchTokenUsingPasswordFlow(userName, password);
      //console.log('got back from server a token: ' + token);
      console.log('login check isadmin: ');
      // store the user in case browser refreshed
      localStorage.setItem('loggedInUser', userName);

      return { success: true, failureMessage: null } as LoginResult;
    }
    catch (err) {
      return { success: false, failureMessage: "Login failed." } as LoginResult;
    }
}
```

My asp.net core backend controller login endpoint is as below:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Login()
{
    var oidRequest = HttpContext.GetOpenIddictServerRequest();
    if (oidRequest.IsPasswordGrantType())
    {
        var validationResult = await authService.ValidateCredentialsIdentity(oidRequest.Username, oidRequest.Password);
        if (validationResult.IsSuccess)
        {
            Claim claimName = new Claim(OpenIddictConstants.Claims.Name, validationResult.Value.DisplayName as string);
            Claim claimEmail = new Claim(OpenIddictConstants.Claims.Email, validationResult.Value.EmailAddress as string);

            Claim claimSubject = new Claim(OpenIddictConstants.Claims.Subject, validationResult.Value.UserId as string);
            claimSubject.SetDestinations(
                OpenIddictConstants.Destinations.IdentityToken,
                OpenIddictConstants.Destinations.AccessToken
            );

            var claimsPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(new[]
            {
                claimName,
                claimEmail,
                claimSubject
            }, authenticationType: validationResult.Value.AuthenticationType));

            var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(
                claimsPrincipal,
                new AuthenticationProperties(),
                OpenIddictServerAspNetCoreDefaults.AuthenticationScheme
            );

            claimsPrincipal.SetScopes(new[]
            {
                OpenIddictConstants.Scopes.OpenId,
                OpenIddictConstants.Scopes.Email,
                OpenIddictConstants.Scopes.Profile,
                OpenIddictConstants.Scopes.Roles
            }.Intersect(oidRequest.GetScopes()));

            claimsPrincipal.SetResources("resource-server");
            if (claimsPrincipal.HasScope(OpenIddictConstants.Scopes.Profile))
            {
                claimName.SetDestinations(OpenIddictConstants.Destinations.IdentityToken);
            }

            if (claimsPrincipal.HasScope(OpenIddictConstants.Scopes.Email))
            {
                claimEmail.SetDestinations(OpenIddictConstants.Destinations.IdentityToken);
            }

            //return SignIn(ticket.Principal, ticket.Properties, ticket.AuthenticationScheme);
            return SignIn(claimsPrincipal);
        }
    }
}
```

I was able to hit the login endpoint and step through it to see that the user's userName and password were correctly passed into it and it was able to find and retrieve the correct user from database to form the `claimsPrincipal`, in the original core3.1 version the `return SignIn(claimsPrincipal, properties, AuthenticationScheme)` call will give back a token that will be saved into the browser's `localStorage`, then the app will be signed in. But after updating to core6.0, the only way it works is to call the `return SignIn(claimsPrincipal)` version, in the Chrome inspection window, I can see it generated `.AspNetCore.Identity.Application` and in the `set-cookies` Header section as below:

```
Identity.External=CfDJ8A5FE2Hy6ApAkXslv_i3QqEIBkEMfcvnOl0dfuAjI4Ret_8XMJVQNiLUoYJMQ7HNEJ-n2UlkmUoFq1SVga2p5hFcOmxVx3K...

.AspNetCore.Identity.Application=CfDJ8A5FE2Hy6ApAkXslv_i3QqFSm5etXjnxN9MXVQRakrKx8gbEJuzqttsrNFVzmQk1VELoMp-Hr3Jco5JeIBbqbWWn5m9_uNKeR...
```

But it is not setting the token in the localStorage for my application like it does previously in Core3.1 version. Plus, at the `oauthService.fetchTokenUsingPasswordFlow()` call in angular code, it gives out the null error message as below:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'access_token')
    at Object.next (main.js:1:413715)
    at Le.next (main.js:1:3494)
    at le._next (main.js:1:3174)
    at le.next (main.js:1:2864)
    at main.js:1:8448
    at Oh._next (main.js:1:7969)
    at Oh.next (main.js:1:2864)
    at main.js:1:231208
    at Oh._next (main.js:1:7969)
    at Oh.next (main.js:1:2864)
```

I am not sure what would be the next step in debugging this. My Asp.Net core packages are as below:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer(6.0.16)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore(6.0.16)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions(6.0.16)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore(6.0.16)
OpenIddict(4.2.0)
OpenIddict.AspNetCore(4.2.0)
OpenIddict.EntityFramworkCore(4.2.0)
```